# Run same web application on multiple linux systems (AWS EC2) with version control

Tags: php, git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, version

I'm wondering what the best approach is to run a application on multiple Linux servers.
Using EC2 AWS linux on different zones.
The web application is the same on each zone, using a different database for each application which is defined in a single config file.
At the moment when I update the application I have to manually update every single server, which is very much work and a high risk for mistakes.

What service or approach could I use to easily update all applications on all servers to the latest version, with excluding some files, I was thinking about Github, but I'm not sure if this is the right thing to use in a production environment.

Also does AWS might have a solution for this?

Thank you,
Roel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What service or approach could I use to easily update all applications on all servers to the latest version, with excluding some files,

The AWS services designed for this sort of thing are AWS CodePipeline/CodeBuild/CodeDeploy. Your code could be stored in a Git repository in AWS CodeCommit, or GitHub.

> I was thinking about Github, but I'm not sure if this is the right thing to use in a production environment.

If you mean GitHub Actions, there are plenty of people using that in production. If you have *specific* concerns about using that in production then include those concerns in your question.

Comment: Thanks Mark, this helps me already to know where to do research, I'm going to look into these options. Thanks!